# Rails adding reference to related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following setup to handle categories and sub categories.

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :subcategories
  has_many :products ,:through => :subcategories
end
```

Subcategory.rb

```
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :products
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

Do I need to add a **category_id:integer & subcategory_id:integer** to the products model make it work, or does Rails handle this for me automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to add category_id and subcategory_id to your models migration file in order to make it work. Rails doesn't do it for you unless you're using `rails generate` syntax wisely.
For eg. first you create `Category` model

```
rails generate model Category name:string
```

Then you create `Subcategory` model passing category as references.

```
rails generate model Subcategory name:string category:references
```

And then you create `Product` model passing subcategory as references

```
rails generate model Product name:string subcategory:references
```

This will automatically add `category_id` and `subcategory_id` to migration files. You will have to write the relations in your model yourself though(i.e., only the `has_many` part)

If you haven't done it by mistake you can create a new migration by `rails generate` command or manually.

```
rails g migration AddCategoryRefToSubcategories category:references
rails g migration AddSubcategoryRefToProducts subcategory:references
```

This will create the appropriate migrations files for you, then run `rake db:migrate`. :)

Comment: Hi Kumar, How would I go about writing this as a migration? (rails generate migration AddReferenceToProducts) then add the other answer?

Comment: `rails generate migration AddSubcategoryRefToProducts subcategory:references` This should create the appropriate migration.

Comment: Would I also need to do the same with Category = Subcategory relationship?

Comment: Yes, indeed. `rails g migration AddCategoryRefToSubcategory category:references`. Check your newly created migration files

Comment: Brilliant - can you update your answer to include comments so other people can reference :)

Comment: I'm just doing that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need add  `category_id:integer & subcategory_id:integer` in Product model.

they should be written in migration file. like this :

```
create_table :products do |t|
    t.references :category, :subcategory
    ...
end
```

Or, maybe i didn't understand your question ?

Comment: I created the products model before category, would references just create ID's anyway?

Comment: sorry for late. rails g migration AddCategoryToProduct , you will get a migration file, and then you can manually `add_column :products, :category_id, :integer` same things for subcategory.